# Hide text labels of X-Axis in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I have the following simple Excel table:

```
         A         B          C           D        E        F
1        Q1        Q2         Q3         Q4
2      2.500     1.000      3.000      4.000
3
```

Based on this data I created a bar chart looking like this:

[image]

All this works fine so far.

---

Now I want to hide the `text labels` of the `X-Axis`. 
Therefore I tried this:

```
Step 1: Click on Format Axis
Step 2: Click on Number
Step 3: Go to Custom
Step 4: Add ;;; into line Format Code
```

However, this only works if the labels of the `X-Axis` are numbers. 
In my case they are text.

Do you have any idea how I can hide `text labels` of the `X-Axis` without deleting the `X-Axis` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When formatting the axis, just set the Axis Labels dropdown to None.

Comment: Perfect. Exaclty what I needed.